# Why does Google Page Experience show 0% Good URLs when most of the URLs have green scores in Pagespeed for FCP, LCP, FID etc.?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, core-web-vitals

The website has around 300 URLs.

There are no Mobile Usability Issues reported in the google search console.

There are no Security Issues reported in the google search console.

There are no Ad experience issues reported in the google search console.

The Website uses HTTPS and that shows up green in the google search console as well.

---

There are 50 URLs (out of ~300) discovered by google search console with problems in LCP.
All the URL are in pending status (not failed).

Testing each of the 50 reported URLs 1 by 1 using https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ we discover that all of them have

- all scores above 90% (so GOOD/FAST category)
- all FCP, LCP, CLS in the green zone

Some of the links have some issues with Time to Interactive, but only a smaller subset.

The 50 reported URLs are grouped by google search console in 2 groups of "similar URLS".

---

Also, after testing using Pagespeed Insights all 300 URLs 1 by 1 multiple times, there are at least 150 URLs (around 50%), even with the most pesimistic estimates, that have EVERY metric Green (Lab Data Only, since Field Data not available):

- FCP < 1800 ms (GREEN)
- LCP < 2500 ms (GREEN)
- TBT < 100 ms (GREEN)
- CLS < 0.1 (GREEN)
- Interactive < 3800 ms (GREEN)
- Speed Index < 3400 ms (GREEN)
- Category FAST

The Google Search Console Report has been run multiple times. At least one full 28-day cycle.
The results are updating at the moment as well.

The site started since launch with 0% Good URLs and in less than a month went up to 10% good URLs then back to 0% Good URLs.

I understand that the feedback is not immediate, and that the data is updated a different timeframes from different sources, but 1 month should be enough time to start registering those 150 good URLs.

The Origin Summary Data doesn't look too good, but even that shows 50% green.

---

- This is how they calculate the scores: [Lighthouse performance scoring](https://web.dev/performance-scoring/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown)
- This is the most recent FAQ Google: [Google FAQ March 2021](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/104436075/core-web-vitals-page-experience-faqs-updated-march-2021?hl=en)
- These are the tools to use to measure metrics: [Core Vitals Tools](https://web.dev/vitals-tools/)
- This is hwo they update the data: [Update Search Console Data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/10218333#critical_issue)

---

**Question 1:** What else can I do to find out why google search console is not discovering any of the 150 good URLs from the website?

It can't be just a matter of time since I've been seeing frequent updates in the past month going from 0% to 10% and back to 0%, right? The most recent update was yesterday.

---